# HOw do I Give VLANs internet access?

Tags: networking, server, internet, iptables

The challenge that I am faced with is as follows.

I need to give internet access to several VLANs via a single Ubuntu 16.04 router.

The VLANs are 8021q tagged and arrive at the router on interface ens1f1.
VLANs are named vlan10, vlan20, vlan30, and vlan40.
The internet uplink is connected to enp0s25.
Enp0s25 has a static public IP address assigned by the ISP.
The upstream device connected to Enp0s25 is not VLAN capable.

I ask you sage and wizened engineers or packet manglers out there if you would please explain to me how I can route, bridge, NAT, or catapult packets between those VLANs and that great tangle of plumbing we call the internet.
In the meantime, I shall retreat to my cupboard muttering error 418 (RFC 2324).

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: Do you use any type of firewall?  `iptables`, `ufw`, etc.?  I have to ask because if you are using `ufw` it'll be a little bit trickier, if you're using `iptables` it won't be as hard, but if you're not using any firewall you're already breaking the cardinal rule of server admin.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer assumes you use an `iptables` firewall on your 'router', and not something 'easier' like `ufw`, *and* that [you have properly set up the router](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan) to handle VLANs on the given interface.

What you're looking for is called "NAT".  This is done by default on many routers, however by default isn't done on Linux systems.

You'll need to enable IPv4 forwarding also in the system to make it work.  Add this to the end of `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

You can get that to apply by doing `sudo sysctl -p` afterwards.  This enables the ability to forward traffic through.

Since your default Internet route is out to the Public Internet, but you want to set up NAT so that the other VLAN machines can go out to the Internet via your system, you would need to set up something like this in `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ip.add.re.ss/24 ! -d ip.add.re.ss/24 -m comment --comment "Allow vlanXX to go to the Internet, masquerade as the public IP." -j MASQUERADE
```

This is a rule in the NAT table for how to route traffic after it's arrived at the system.  You'll need three of these rules, one for each subnet of each VLAN.  Adjust `ip.add.re.ss` and `vlanXX` accordingly to match the information for your network specifically.

You also need to have an `ACCEPT` rule in the `filter` table of `iptables` for `FORWARD`, and you would typically do this by interface, like this, updating the `XX` items to be the vlan number:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -o ens1f1.XX -m comment --comment "NAT for vlanXX" -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i ens1f1.XX -m comment --comment "NAT for vlanXX" -j ACCEPT
```

Once you've done this, you need to make sure you save the `iptables` rules.  Ideally you would do this if you didn't have it installed first, and tell it "Yes" when it asks to save your rules:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

... and that would set up the `iptables` rules at boot properly as well as save the rules.  If you already have `iptables-persistent`, then you need to update the rules it loads:

```
sudo su -c 'iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4'
```

... and now the NAT `MASQUERADE` rule will be in place every time you boot.

Comment: Dear Thomas,

Thank you so much for your rapid and thorough reply.
So I don't need any bridges to solve this?
The router in question still lives in my development lab, I would never let anything attach to the wild without a firewall. Although I looked into ufw, I couldn't see it helping me. Even so, my attempts using IPtables didn't get far either.
I shall brew up a solution according to your recipe and report back.

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: @KevinAnderson You don't need a bridge, no.  Especially if the VLANs are directly linked to the port itself.  You just need simple NAT.  (This NAT only lets it go out, it doesn't let unrelated traffic back into the systems, so if you are running a webserver on 1.2.3.4 on vlan30, you can't access the webserver from the public IP address without much more complicated NAT rules)

Comment: @KevinAnderson *Also* you need to have the machine set up properly for 802.1Q VLAN tagging, per the linked "VLAN" help article from the Ubuntu Help documentation in order for all this to work properly.  Without knowing more about your setup though, and assuming it's just straight VLANs and this is a dedicated 'gateway' box, there shouldn't be an issue.  If the VLANs are internal virtual ethernet interfaces or something, though, that makes it more complex.  The basics are here, though.